# Same library but different names in fedora and ubuntu?

Tags: c, json, automake

I'm building an application that makes use of json encoding and decoding. I original developed the application under fedora and made use of the json-c library. Under Debian type distros this same library is called libjson.

I'm positive it's the same library as my code works without any modification once I change the library anem. I really don't want to have to maintain two different code bases just for this. Is there any way to use some sort of conditional in autoconf to help with this? Especially in terms of linking the proper library in Makefile.am? Additionally, how would I set up the .h files to use the right name in the right distro? Is there some sort of globally accessible DEFINE I can use for this?

eg

```
#ifdef debian
#include libjson
#endif
#ifdef fedora
#include json-c
#endif
```

Any clue would be helpful.

Chris

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same library, they may be two different libraries with the same interface.

Comment: Let me explain more effectively. In debian they have a package called libjson. This seems to be the same exact package as json-c you can get with apt-get under fedora. I did a cursory verification of the calls but you are right, I did not check to see if it was the exact same code. However, you'd think with calls like json_object_to_json_string_ext and using identical structs it would likely be the same library but I'll verify in a moment.

Comment: You don't want to detect the distribution. You want to detect the feature, which is kind of the whole point of autoconf. Does the platform have libjson? Then use it. No? Then does the platform have json-c? Then use that instead.  Your header would be like `#ifdef HAVE_LIBJSON`.  It's all in the manual:  http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Files

Comment: As note: I just confirmed it's the same library. When I downloaded the source package for libjson0 under ubuntu I received "Picking 'json-c' as source package instead of 'libjson0'"

Comment: indiv, I think I understand. This is my first time using autoconf and I mostly just pulled up examples. So I don't have to specifically define the library I want to link against in Makefile.am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such distro packaging pecularities are solved with configuration scripts. I put here a script for cmake that solves that problem. If you are using autotools - I think you can write the same from my script.

```
# - Try to find the JSON C library
#
# Once done this will define
#
#  JSON_FOUND    - system has the JSON C library
#  JSON_INCLUDES - JSON C include directory
#  JSON_LIBRARY  - JSON C library

FIND_PATH(
  JSON_INCLUDES
  NAMES json.h
  PATH_SUFFIXES json-c json
  PATHS /usr/include /usr/local/include
  )

MESSAGE(STATUS "Include ${JSON_INCLUDES}")

FIND_LIBRARY(JSON_LIBRARY
  NAMES json-c json
  PATHS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
  )

IF(JSON_LIBRARY AND JSON_INCLUDES)
  SET(JSON_LIBRARIES ${JSON_LIBRARY})
  SET(JSON_FOUND "YES")
ELSE()
  SET(JSON_FOUND "NO")
ENDIF()

IF(JSON_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "JSON C: ${JSON_LIBRARIES}")
ELSE()
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find JSON C library")
ENDIF()

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(JSON_LIBRARIES JSON_INCLUDES JSON_FOUND)

# End of file
```

The same for autotools (modify your configure.ac):

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([JSON_C], [json],,[
  PKG_CHECK_MODULES([JSON_C], [json-c])
]
```

Comment: Please do not sign your posts with "cheers", "best regards" etc.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, better?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'm sorry if I break the culture. I remove this from other posts.

Comment: Honestly, he really helped me out so signing his post with cheers, best regards, is absolutely fine with me.

Comment: @Chris The "Cheers", "best regards" _didn't_ help you out so no it doesn't belong there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank both indiv and Tanuki for their help. I was able to find a solution with their help.

I ended up going with the follow in configure.ac

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([json_tokener_parse_ex], [json-c libjson], [], [
    echo "JSON-C (fedora) and/or LibJson (debian) library ) is missing."
    exit -1])
AC_CHECK_LIB([json-c], [json_tokener_parse_ex], [LIBJSONC=true], [], [])
AM_CONDITIONAL([LINK_LIBJSONC], [test x$LIBJSONC = xtrue])
AC_CHECK_LIB([libjson], [json_tokener_parse_ex], [LIBJSON=true], [], [])
AM_CONDITIONAL([LINK_LIBJSON], [test x$LIBJSON = xtrue])
```

Which let me use the following in Makefile.am

```
if LINK_LIBJSON
  USE_LIBJSON=-llibjson
endif
if LINK_LIBJSONC
  USE_LIBJSON=-ljson-c
endif
AM_LDFLAGS= $(USE_LIBJSON) ...
```